# Semantic issue: Property 'text' not found on object of type 'UISlider'

Tags: xcode

When I try to run it though, I get an error which says "Semantic issue: Property 'text' not found on object of type 'UISlider'"

What's wrong here?

Here is the code from the header file:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BIDViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *sliderLabel;

- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender;



@end
```

Implementation file:

```
    #import "BIDViewController.h"

@implementation BIDViewController
@synthesize sliderLabel;
@synthesize nameField;
@synthesize numberField;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setNameField:nil];
    [self setNumberField:nil];
    [self setSliderLabel:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender
{
[sender resignFirstResponder];
}   

- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender
 {
    [nameField resignFirstResponder];
    [numberField resignFirstResponder];
 }

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender
{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    int progressAsInt = (int)roundf(slider.value);
    sliderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",progressAsInt];
}

@end
```

Comment: Where are you declaring your `sliderLabel`?

Comment: There is a "@synthesize sliderLabel;" declaration on the implementation page, and in the -(void)viewDidUnload method, there is a "[self setSliderLabel:nil];
" statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your `sliderLabel` has been declared as an object of class `UISlider`, when it should be `UILabel`. Can you verify the sliderLabel's `@property` declaration in your header file?

Comment: Thank you. Let me give you more context by pasting all the code from the .m, .h files.

Comment: @pdenlinger: The .m file is unnecessary here. Scott Forbes is correct. Your `sliderLabel` property is declared as a `UISlider*` when it should be a `UILabel*`, and the synthesized ivar (which is what you're actually accessing (you should probably fix that)) is inheriting that type declaration.

Comment: Thank you Kevin and Scott. Changed it from UISlider* to UILabel, then hooked up the slider to the File's Owner and to the label as outlet, and it worked fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same message on NSManagedObject. My solution is set "Always Search User Paths" in "Search Paths" of target's Build Settings to "No"
Hope that could help too.